# wso2 svn update - E205011: Failure occurred processing one or more externals definitions

Tags: svn, wso2

I am trying to `svn update` the 4.0.0 platform branch, but repeatedly hit the error:

`E205011: Failure occurred processing one or more externals definitions`

My `svn info` output:

```
C:\wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_branch_400>svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /cygdrive/c/wso2/src/wso2carbon_platform_branch_400
URL: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0
Relative URL: ^/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0
Repository Root: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2
Repository UUID: a5903396-d722-0410-b921-86c7d4935375
Revision: 176686
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: manu@wso2.com
Last Changed Rev: 176658
Last Changed Date: 2013-06-28 19:28:29 +0100 (Fri, 28 Jun 2013)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please check the whole log to and see which svn externals are failing. Try "svn update" and carefully check all logs printed. It might be easier if you redirect output to a text file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this, I deleted the old checked out branch and checked it out again.  This time, no problem.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what specifically can cause this problem.  It seems that an error higher up in the output can cause this problem again.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem intermittently on a Jenkins server that checkouts performs svn update on a repository with externals.  Same thing here, performing a full checkout instead solves the problem.  But I feel we are not getting at the root cause of the problem.