# wso2 svn (cygwin) update throws "Out of memory" error

Tags: svn, cygwin, wso2

I am trying to svn update the 4.0.0 platform branch, but have hit the error:

```
Fetching external item into 'features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.server.feature/4.0.8/src/main/resources/apimgt':
Out of memory - terminating application.
      1 [main] svn 8224 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to svn.exe.stackdump
```

I have run into other issues with `svn update` - see my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381147/wso2-svn-update-e205011-failure-occurred-processing-one-or-more-externals-def)

My `svn info` output:

```
C:\wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_branch_400>svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /cygdrive/c/wso2/src/wso2carbon_platform_branch_400
URL: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0
Relative URL: ^/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0
Repository Root: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2
Repository UUID: a5903396-d722-0410-b921-86c7d4935375
Revision: 176686
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: manu@wso2.com
Last Changed Rev: 176658
Last Changed Date: 2013-06-28 19:28:29 +0100 (Fri, 28 Jun 2013)
```

My `svn --version` output:

```
C:\wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_branch_400>svn --version
svn, version 1.8.0 (r1490375)
   compiled Jun 19 2013, 10:42:54 on i686-pc-cygwin
```

Comment: Do you always get this error? Did you try closing all other applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I deleted the old checked out branch and checked it out again.  This time, no problem.